# swift firebase phone auth error "verifyPhoneNumber:completion is deprecated

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

error "verifyPhoneNumber:completion is deprecated

```
    PhoneAuthProvider.provider().verifyPhoneNumber(PhoneNum.text!) { (verificationID, error) in
        if let error = error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)

        }
        // Sign in using the verificationID and the code sent to the user
        else {
            UserDefaults.standard.set(verificationID, forKey: "authVerificationID")
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "segue", sender: self)
        }
    }
```

update image
[image]

Comment: Try `verifyPhoneNumber:UIDelegate:completion:`

Comment: Can you provide which version of Firebase/Auth pod you are using with which xcode.

Comment: The new API is documented here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/phone-auth#send-a-verification-code-to-the-users-phone

Comment: Thanks for the help from everyone. Thanks Rajesh, I use verifyPhoneNumber:UIDelegate:completion: to dismiss the warning. But i got another error and I still received the verification code. Please see my update image.

Comment: Have you resolved this yet!?

Comment: You found a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

I have similar issue and I followed @bojeil's link and I got away with all warnings.
Note: I am using firebase without the Pods. 
Following is my code:

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Double-Check:", message: "Is this your correct mobile number? We'll send a text message with a confirmation code to this number:\n \(userMobileNumber.text!)", preferredStyle: .alert)

let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Yes, Send", style: .default) { 
    (alert: UIAlertAction!) in PhoneAuthProvider.provider().verifyPhoneNumber(fullMobileNumber, uiDelegate: nil) {
        (verificationID, error) in if error != nil {
            print("error: \(String(describing: error?.localizedDescription))")
        } else {
            let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
            defaults.set(verificationID, forKey: "authVID")
            // MARK:- Activity Indicator code begins

            // MARK:- Activity Indicator ends

            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "verifyCode", sender: Any?.self)
        }
    }
}
```